# How to write a ratio in the form of n:1

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm calculating ratios in the form of n:1 and cannot figure out what the correct result should be in the following scenario:

Scenario: Calculate the number of Interviews to Offers for jobs.

- 0 interviews, 0 offers
- 6 interviews, 0 offers
- 0 interviews, 6 offers

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 1):

The third one is 0:1. The others can't be expressed in the form n:1.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt and helpful response Gerry - makes sense.